# How to know which all events are being triggered during a Yii application lifecycle?

Tags: php, yii

I need to know this because I am unable to save my User model by calling a function setStatus(), which I'm trying to call from a class extending from yii\base\component.

```
public  function setStatus()
    {
     if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $this->status = 1;
        $this->save();
     }
     else {
         $this->status = 0;
         $this->save();
     }

    }
```

And here is the component class

```
Class StatusComponent extends Component
 {
     public function init(){
        $user = New User;
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
        $user->setStatus();
        echo $user->getStatus();
        parent::init();
     } 
 }
```

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6405-no-modelvalidation-errors-but-save-return-false/) is a workaround suggested on Yii forums which says that it may be due to some event returning 'false'.. If this is the case, how do I know?

Comment: Show validation rules form your User model.

Comment: Great guess! Actually I just figured it out by using the $model->getErrors() method and it said "status is invalid". there was a 'range' defined for the status field in the rules. Waiting to accept if you post an answer.  please don't forget to upVote() if you think this question is going to help the community. :) cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `save()` method here, validation check will be performed on status save:

```
    $this->status = 1;
    $this->save();
```

To get save errors you can do something like this:

```
    $this->status = 1;
    if ($this->validate())
        $this->save(false);
    else {
        echo "There was some errors while saving user!";
        die(print_r($this->getErrors()));// this line for debug
    }
```

`save(false)` disabling validation before save.

To address the original question about listing all events, [x-debug](http://xdebug.org/) or similar stack tracing tools may be used.